# SQL Statement INSERT, on duplicate columns UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL Table that contains a list of items that users can have linked to their profile. The SQL table looks something like this:

```
Item_Activity_ID       Item_ID      User_ID     Status    Date-Added    

     1                  1           1             1         2015-06-08
     2                  2           2             1         2015-06-08
     3                  1           1             0         2015-06-09
```

The entry shows that someone with the user with id of 1 added item id 1 twice, and the only thing that was changed was the date and status. I want to make it so that when given an INSERT statement such as:

```
INSERT INTO items (Item_ID, User_ID, Status, Date_Added) VALUES ('$x', '$y', 1, CURDATE()) IF EXISTS SOME Item_ID = $x AND User_ID = $y UPDATE items SET Status = 1, Date_Added = CURDATE() WHERE Item_ID = $x AND User_ID = $y
```

Item_Activity_ID is an auto_incremented primary key index. How can I accomplish this in one query? Two users can have the same item, but where should never be repeat entries of the same user id and item id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First, create a *unique* index for `Item_ID, UserID` combination,
- Then, use the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

  ```
  INSERT INTO items (Item_ID, User_ID, Status, Date_Added) 
  VALUES ('$x', '$y', 1, CURDATE()) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Status = VALUES(Status), Date_Added = VALUES(Date_Added))
  ```

---

P.S. make sure to sanitize `$x` and `$y` to prevent SQL injections!

Comment: Thanks Alex, for such a simplest and informative info

Answer (score 1):

I would start by adding a unique key index:

```
ALTER TABLE items
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_UserItem UNIQUE (Item_ID,User_ID);
```

Then, you can just modify your insert query:

```
INSERT INTO items (Item_ID, User_ID, Status, Date_Added) VALUES ('$x', '$y', 1, CURDATE()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Status=VALUES(1), Date_Added=VALUES(CURDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform the update first supposing that the user and item already exist. Then check if this update affects any rows (using @@rowcount, in SQL Server). 
If not then perform an insert.
Don't forget to put the above two statements in a transaction... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Normal way would be to set a composite constraint at the db level. If you are using mysql and phpmyadmin you do this in the table structure view.

Check both fields (I guess 'user_id' and 'item_id') and click the 'unique' button.

After that is set you can just append
 `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status =1, date_added=CURDATE()`.

It will update the row that violated the constraint you created